# How to check if file exist in a diretory, and overwrite or create

Tags: bash, shell

i have a script that manipulate text and create files in one diretory by name/acronym.
like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="$HOME/folha1/it/colaboradores/users.txt"
out="$HOME/folha1/it/colaboradores/LDAP/"

#check if file exist, if exist rewrite for up


while IFS=';' read -r Act Nome Email Numero Skype; do
     cat  << EOF >> "$out"/"$Act"

Nome: $Nome
Email: $Email
Numero: $Numero
Skype: $Skype
EOF
done < "$input"
```

but when i try to see if there is a file i try this

```
#!/bin/bash

input="$HOME/folha1/it/colaboradores/users.txt"
out="$HOME/folha1/it/colaboradores/LDAP"

if [ "$(ls -A $out)" ]; then
    rm -rf $HOME/folha1/it/colaboradores/LDAP/*
fi
while IFS=';' read -r Act Nome Email Numero Skype; do
     cat  << EOF >> "$out"/"$Act"
        Nome: $Nome
        Email: $Email
        Numero: $Numero
        Skype: $Skype
        EOF
    done < "$input"
```

but if they have files the script at the moment remove but not create again..
and i have this erros:

```
[teste@oel73 ex02]$ ./ex026.sh
./ex026.sh: line 16: warning: here-document at line 10 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./ex026.sh: line 17: syntax error: unexpected end of file
[teste@oel73 ex02]$
```

I cannot see what is wrong in script

I change for that :

```
#!/bin/bash

input="$HOME/folha1/it/colaboradores/users.txt"
out="$HOME/folha1/it/colaboradores/LDAP/"

if [ "$(ls -A $out)" ]; then
        rm -rf $HOME/folha1/it/colaboradores/LDAP/*
fi
while IFS=';' read -r Act Nome Email Numero Skype; do
     var=$(cat <<-EOF
        Nome: $Nome
        Email: $Email
        Numero: $Numero
        Skype: $Skype
        EOF
    )
    echo $var > "$out"/"$Act"
        done < "$input"
```

but i still have :

```
[teste@oel73 ex02]$ ./ex028.sh 
./ex028.sh: line 10: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
./ex028.sh: line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

with your comments i put this :

```
#!/bin/bash
input="$HOME/folha1/it/colaboradores/users.txt"
out="$HOME/folha1/it/colaboradores/LDAP/"

if [ "$(ls -A "$out")" ]; then
        rm -rf "$HOME"/folha1/it/colaboradores/LDAP/*
fi
while IFS=';' read -r Act Nome Email Numero Skype; do
     cat  << EOF >> "$out"/"$Act"
Nome: $Nome
Email: $Email
Numero: $Numero
Skype: $Skype
EOF
done < "$input"
```

Comment: The EOF needs to be on a new line, alone, i.e. it can not be indented.

Comment: how can i change ? i put int the other ways EOF , i will put in the code now, but still have error

Comment: Welcome to SO. Check script here first  https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: yeah, i know, it gave me the errors, , i used it , but i cannot fix them alone, that's why i'm looking for help

Comment: ok that's result nice, i see the problem i will post

Comment: Remove the indentation. yes or use `printf`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `test` command to check if file exits.

```
if [ -f /path/to/file ]; then
  # do something here.
fi
```

Or

```
[ -f /path/to/file ] && rm -rf /path/to/file
```

Comment: yeah nice, i will implement